# How to find what device is connected to USB port (HID or Disk drive) in C++

Tags: c++, winapi, usb, usb-drive

I have managed to enumerate all the connected USB ports using SetupDi calls. Sample code is available at this [link](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/259695).

Please could any one tell me how can I find what device is connected to USB port like whether it is any HID device or any Disk drive?

Thanks.

Comment: does this help http://www.qtcentre.org/threads/31090-How-to-get-vendor-id-and-product-id-of-a-USB-device-on-windows-system

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend looking at the USBView sample in the WDK. If you are unfamiliar with this, simply run it - this tool walks the entire USB tree on the system and prints out information and descriptor listings for each device.

In your case, I'd start at the RefreshTree() function in this sample, you can then follow the code to see how it enumerates the host controllers, hubs and finally devices. For each device that you find you can look at the bInterfaceClass in the interface descriptors to find out what types of interfaces it is advertising (in your case 0x03 for HID Interface Class and 0x08 for Mass Storage Class).

The easiest way to get the source to this sample is to install the 7.1.0 WDK which is currently available here:
http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=11800